# Rで中央値medianを計算する際のエラー

Tags: r

CSVで読み込んだデータのうち一つのカラムの中央値を求めようとするとエラーが出てしまいます。
データは2カラムのみで、12行、該当カラムはdbl型式です。
原因がもしわかればご教示いただければ幸いです。

```
mean(df$y)
#error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used[1] "error"
```

**追記**
以下でも同様のエラーが出ます

```
df2 <- c(12,13,14)
median(df2)
```

Comment: 手元の環境の `R version 3.6.3` で `median(df2)` を実行すると結果として `13` が表示されてエラーにはなりません。そちらでお使いの R のバージョンと OS は何でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！あら、では環境の問題なのでしょうか…
こちらは下記の環境です。
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: 複数の値を取るのが普通の `mean` や `median` で最初の1要素だけを使う, というエラーがでるのは不自然です. `mean`, `median` とだけ実行した時, それぞれ `<environment: namespace:base>` , <environment: namespace:stats>
 などは表示されますか? 違うものが表示された場合は何か別のオブジェクトで「上書き」されている可能性があります

Comment: なるほど。。。それでは vanilla R で実行するとどうなるでしょう？ コマンドラインで `R -q --vanilla -e 'df2 <- c(12, 13, 14); median(df2);'` を実行してみて下さい。

Comment: @user12399423 ありがとうございます。なるほど。。確認したところエラ〜メッセージは下記で、特にenvironment関連のメッセージは出ませんでした。```the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used[1] "error"```

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます！こちらも試して見たのですが、別のエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。```Error: unexpected string constant in "R -q --vanilla -e 'df2 <- c(12, 13, 14); median(df2);'"```

Comment: そのエラーは `mean(df2)` と同じですよね? 私は計算結果ではなく関数オブジェクト  `mean` だけを呼び出した場合の結果で原因がわかるかもしれないという意図でした. @metropolis さんの案に対しても, ターミナルで実行していますか? どうもR上でシステムコマンドを実行しようとしたときのエラーメッセージに見えるのですが...

Comment: R studioで全てのコードを実行しています。ターミナルとはエラーメッセージが異なるかもしれません。
今朝RとRstudio全てを消去して再度インストールしたと所、元々のコードでも@user12399423 さんの方法でも問題なく結果が出ました。Rstudio側の問題だったのかもしれません。
ご協力いただき、本当にありがとうございました

Comment: 解決につながったのでしたら幸いです. ですが, どうもRのコマンドとターミナルのコマンドを混同なさっているようですので指摘させていただきます. 両者は別物で, それぞれもう一方の場所に書き込んでも実行することはできません

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。Rとターミナルは実行環境が全く別とのこと、理解いたしました。